# Docker CMD instruction execution

Tags: docker, apt-get, luarocks

My docker file has the following instructions

```
CMD ["luarocks","install",luasocket"]
```

When I try to build image, it builds successfully but `luasocket` is not installed yet all on my docker.
But when I execute this statement manually after "`sudo apt-get update`" on docker everything is going smooth.

Why it is being executed properly after "update" manually on command line.  Even though my docker contains "`update`" command, why is it failing in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I execute this statement manually after "sudo apt-get update" on docker every thing is going smooth

If you execute a `sudo apt-get update` in a *container* session (ie., after a `docker run`), anything done by the `apt-get` command will be reset on the next `docker run` (next container).

Make sure to include a `RUN apt-get update` in your Dockerfile if the command `luarocks install luasocket` needs it to complete sucessfully.

More generally, this install command (`luarocks install luasocket`) should not be a `CMD`, but a `RUN` directive in order to bake into the image the installation of `luasocket`.